# QWebFrame addToJavaScriptWindowObject() objects are undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, qt, qwebkit

I have started to dig in to C++ and Qt again, and have been mucking around with the WebKit Javascript/Qt bindings. I've got all the moving parts working, with the exception of my QObject subclass being "undefined" on the Javascript side. Here's the simple test app I'm having trouble with:

My main window implementation:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

// instantiate a webview
QWebView *webview = new QWebView(this);
webview->setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 300);
webview->setUrl(QUrl("file://localhost/Users/kyle/Sites/tests/qt/index.html"));

// instantiate and attach our QObject
hello *h = new hello();

QWebFrame *frame = webview->page()->mainFrame();
frame->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("Hello", h);

// show the window
webview->show();
}
```

Hello.cpp

```
...snip...

QString hello::say()
{
    return QString("Kyle");
}
```

Hello.h

```
...snip includes...

class hello : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    hello();
    Q_INVOKABLE QString say();

};
```

The above-mentioned index.html file does a simple `alert(Hello.say())` call, but doing `typeof Hello`, I get undefined.

I'm a bit rusty with C++, and pretty new to Qt, so I'm sure this is a noob mistake, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objects can't be inserted in the page at any time. You should put that line:

```
frame->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("Hello", h);
```

in a slot connected to the [`javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()` signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#javaScriptWindowObjectCleared) of the `QWebFrame` and move some code around, so you can access the frame from that slot.

See also the [Form Extractor example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-webkit-formextractor-example.html) included with Qt.

Answer (score 0):

The core of this is really implemented in two methods, which are
shown below:

```
void MyApi::setWebView( QWebView *view )
{
    QWebPage *page = view->page();
    frame = page->mainFrame();

    attachObject();
    connect(frame, &QWebFrame::javaScriptWindowObjectCleared, this, &MyApi::attachObject);
    // old approach
    //connect( frame, SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()), this, SLOT(attachObject()) );
}

void MyApi::attachObject()
{
    frame->addToJavaScriptWindowObject( QString("MyApi"), this );
}
```

This code is all that you need in order to make all of the public slots of the
MyApi object visible to javascript. The MyApi class provides two public slots:

```
public slots:
    void doSomething( const QString &param );
    int doSums( int a, int b );
```

The first slot simply logs a message to the debug output, the second returns
the sum of its two arguments (yes, slots can return things!). They're called
from javascript like this:

```
MyApi.doSomething( 'Hello from JS page 2!!!!' );

sum = MyApi.doSums( 2, 3 );
alert( 'C++ says the sum is ' + sum );
```

The code above was tested in QT5.5, and please note all methods should be put in "public slots" section.

Comment: Your `attachObject()` public slot class method is missing the `frame` object. I fixed it in my case by doing `QWebFrame *frame = ui->myWebViewWidget->page()->mainFrame();`. Other than that, this was exactly what worked for me.

Comment: This is great for injecting my object into the mainFrame() of the QWebView widget, but doesn't seem to work in injecting it into a child IFRAME. What would you try? http://stackoverflow.com/q/33599474/105539